How can I quickly store each group after groupby in polars?
df is a polars DataFrame, the code is following:
for code,data in df.group_by("codeID"):
            if not os.path.isdir(code):
                os.mkdir(code)
            data.write_ipc(code+"/"+trade_date+'.feather')

The dimension of df is 49,861,246 x 15, and it costs half an hour to finish. How to make the process faster on the single machine?
I tried to parallelise the for loop, but the computer doesn't seem to have enough memory.

How did you try to parallelize it? The multiprocessing module? I'm not sure if Polars supports partitioned dataset writes as of yet, perhaps you can try PyArrow's Dataset Writer? e.g. something like pyarrow.dataset.write_dataset(df.to_arrow(), path, partitioning=["codeID"], format="ipc")

Unless you're writing each piece to a different physical drive then parallelizing this won't help as you're going to be IO constrained. How long does it take if you write it all to a single file?
